# Natural numbers combination that sum to another specific number

Tags: python, combinations

If i have two natural numbers, "k" and "n". How can i show all combinations in "k" parts that sum to "n"? I tried this code, but i'd like do exclude the sum with zero from the output tuples.

```
def compositions(k, n):
    if k == 1:
        return [(n,)]

    comp = []
    for i in range(n + 1):
        for t in compositions(k - 1, n - i):
            comp.append((i,) + t)
    return comp
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "combinations in 'k' parts". Are you asking for [partitions of n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) with k parts?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same outputs but without outputs that include zero, you could do the following.

```
def compositions(k, n):
    
    if n==0:
        return []
    
    if k == 1:
        return [(n,)]

    comp = []
    for i in range(1,n + 1):
        for t in compositions(k - 1, n - i):
            comp.append((i,) + t)
    return comp
```

Comment: I tried this, but the first tuple is still (0,n)

Comment: I got this. I added a condition of i>0 right after the second loop. It works! Thank you for the insight!